# How to create full url of store using jQuery in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, jquery, urlbuilder

I was facing one big issue to access base URL of store in custom module through jQuery object in magento 2.

In PHP, generally it can obtain using `$this->getUrl('module/controller/action');` but in jQuery object how we can obtain same ?

In checkout module we seems, there is usage of `this.getUrl()` method. And its working fine.

After giving hours of dedication I found the solution. and It will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

In your jQuery file add `'mage/url'` and create a object of it `'urlBuilder'`.

e.g.

```
define(
        [
        'jquery', 
        'underscore',
        'mage/url',
        'jquery/ui'
        ], function ($, _,urlBuilder) {
       'use strict';


        getCustomUrl: function() {
           return urlBuilder.build('/routeName/controller/actioName');

        }

});
```

And use `getCustomUrl()` function in this jQuery class/widget anywhere.

As per your requirement you can modified it as your best.